# god-scientist building perpetual motion machine

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a short story I read time ago. This is what I recall: some space explorer discovers how a sort of "god-scientist" created the universe in his pursuit for a perpetual motion machine, and in doing so he realizes that life and consciousness are only byproducts of the experiment. That's it, more or less.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't thinking of real life? *DUN DUN DUUUUUUUN*

Comment: Can you clarify how long ago you read it?  Was it a book or magazine (or online), and what country it was printed in?